# SimpleDateFormat Comparison Issue

Tags: java, simpledateformat

I'd like to compare two dates in a string format and return the result in HH:MM:SS:SSS as a String.
When i try running the following with a startDate of `15 Jul 2013 17:08:34.903` and endDate of 
`15 Jul 2013 17:08:51.247` I'd expect to see a result of `00:00:16.344`. Instead i'm getting a diff of `01:00:16.344`. Any ideas why this is happening??

```
private static final SimpleDateFormat DATE_FORMAT = new SimpleDateFormat("d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS");
    private static final SimpleDateFormat DATE_FORMAT_HH_MM_SS = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss.SSS");

    public String calculateDuration(String startDateStr, String endDateStr){

        String methodName = "calculateDuration";
        try {           
            Date startDate = DATE_FORMAT.parse(startDateStr);
            Date endDate = DATE_FORMAT.parse(endDateStr);          
            long diff = endDate.getTime() - startDate.getTime();        
            return DATE_FORMAT_HH_MM_SS.format(diff);
```

Comment: Is this Java? Consider giving it language tag

Comment: I think you should use [*JodaTime*](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) to compute time difference (duration). That will simplify your life.

Comment: By the way, your method doesn't always work if the `calculateDuration` is called from different threads, because `SimpleDateFormat` is not thread safe.

Comment: Yes it's Java, sorry i should have specified that in my original post. My TZ is GMT. Thanks for e suggestion i'll look at JodaTime.

Comment: You are trying to interpret the difference between two timestamps (as in ms since the Unix epoch) as a new timestamp. That won't work. There are no classes in the Java standard API with reasonable support for time periods.

Comment: Do you really have to calculate the difference between two formatted dates?  You'll have a lot fewer headaches if you use `Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis()`.

Comment: I just need the total runtime for an application so i'll consider using `Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis()` instead. Thanks for the advise.

Comment: Java 8 will have better support. Also be aware that SimpleDateFormat in Java 7 is not thread safe but maintains an inner state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JDK Date API is horrible. I recommend using [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) library but if you must use JDK Date API try this code:

```
private static final SimpleDateFormat DATE_FORMAT = new SimpleDateFormat(
        "d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS");

public String calculateDuration(String startDateStr, String endDateStr)
        throws ParseException {

    String methodName = "calculateDuration";
    Date startDate = DATE_FORMAT.parse(startDateStr);
    Date endDate = DATE_FORMAT.parse(endDateStr);

    // in milliseconds
    long diff = endDate.getTime() - startDate.getTime();

    long diffMiliseconds = diff % 1000;
    long diffSeconds = diff / 1000 % 60;
    long diffMinutes = diff / (60 * 1000) % 60;
    long diffHours = diff / (60 * 60 * 1000) % 24;

    return String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d.%02d", diffHours, diffMinutes,
            diffSeconds, diffMiliseconds);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You've not initialized your SimpleDateFormat formatter with a Calendar object, so it is using a default one to do the mapping.  I am guessing that this default Calendar is recognizing DST.   This is not manifest when you .parse() the datetimes, because the DST adjustment cancels out in the subtraction.

When you convert the result to HMS format, the formatter again applies the DST adjustment.  Since there is no subtraction in this step, it appears in your result.

It does seem to me that whenever anybody has a date arithmetic question, the rubber-stamp, knee-jerk reflex response is "use JodaTime."  We all love JodaTime; it is a well-crafted API.  But using it is still an external dependency and unless you -need- it you should not use it.  In my opinion, for this situation you do not need JodaTime at all ... you only need the Java Calendar API to parse your datetimes into Dates.  And that's all you need it for.

Once you have the difference in milliseconds, you really should avoid using a formatter to convert the result back.  Using simple arithmetic will be far more performant:

```
private static final SimpleDateFormat DATE_FORMAT = 
    new SimpleDateFormat("d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS");

private static final int DAYS    = 0;
private static final int HOURS   = 1;
private static final int MINUTES = 2;
private static final int SECONDS = 3;
private static final int MILLIS  = 4;
private final int[] result = new int[MILLIS];

public String calculateDuration(String startDateStr, String endDateStr){

    try {           
        Date startDate = DATE_FORMAT.parse(startDateStr);
        Date endDate = DATE_FORMAT.parse(endDateStr);
    } catch (Exception e) { /* exception processing */ }

    long diff = endDate.getTime() - startDate.getTime();        

    double d; 
    for (int i = DAYS; i <= MILLIS; i++) {    
        switch(i) {
            case DAYS:
                d = ((double) diff) / (86400.0 * 1000.0);
                break;
            case HOURS:
                d = d * 24.0;   break;
            case MINUTES:  case SECONDS:
                d = d * 60.0;   break;
            case MILLIS:
                d = d * 1000.0; break;
        }
        result[i] = (int) Math.floor(d);
        d = d - (double) result[i];
    }
```

At the conclusion of this last `for` loop, the array `result` contains integers that correspond to the number of DAYS, HOURS, MINUTES, SECONDS, and MILLIS derived from your date subtraction.  No objects need to be created, allocated, or invoked in order to get this result.  You can now easily use the `String.format()` function to put these integers into the string format of your choosing.

Comment: I beg to differ in the matter of JodaTime. While I agree that one doesn´t always have to use it, I still like pointing it out for such questions, because it makes dealing with calendar data a LOT easier and some people haven´t heard of it yet. I´m glad I was pointed out to Joda when I first asked something about Calendars and Dates.

Comment: @JannisAlexakis: Subtraction between Date objects frequently does not require a Calendar API.  In this case, using the Calendar API is not only much slower, it also leads to an error since the resulting interval is mapped (somewhat erroneously) to a calendar date.  External dependencies are what they are.  If it is generally agreed that it is better to dispense with them when possible, then I think we can agree that it is possible to dispense with one in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Since in the comments you say that you're simply measuring running time for an application, don't involve Date, SimpleDateFormat, or Calendar at all.

```
long tic = System.nanoTime();
```

...is all you need.  Don't use a cannon to kill a mosquito when you have a fly swatter on hand.